# How can I make a list that contains various types of elements in Python?

Tags: python, list, abaqus

I have the following parameters in a Python file that is used to send commands pertaining to boundary conditions to Abaqus:

```
u1=0.0,
u2=0.0,
u3=0.0,
ur1=UNSET,
ur2=0.0,
ur3=UNSET
```

I would like to place these values inside a list and print that list to a .txt file. I figured I should convert all contents to strings:

```
List = [str(u1), str(u2), str(u3), str(ur1), str(ur2), str(ur3)]
```

This works only as long as the list does not contain "UNSET", which is a command used by Abaqus and is neither an int or str. Any ideas how to deal with that? Many thanks!

Comment: You can make a list that contains various types of elements easily. Just take out all those `str` calls. It sounds like your real issue is reversibly encoding the list as text to save and load the data from a file.

Comment: What exactly does the rest of your "python file" look like? Where is the error you get? If you just write `ur1=UNSET` without defining `UNSET`, then it should be `ur1="UNSET"` instead.

Comment: after answering I start to wonder if you are trying to write code intended to run outside the abaqus environment (where `UNSET` would be defined). If thats the case you should clarify exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNSET` is an Abaqus/cae defined symbolic constant. It has a member `name` that returns the string representation, so you might do something like this:

```
 def tostring(v):
  try:
   return(v.name)
  except:
   return(str(v))
```

then do for example

```
  bc= [0.,1,UNSET]
  print "u1=%s u2=%s u3=%s\n"%tuple([tostring(b) for b in bc])
```

> u1=0. u2=1 u3=UNSET

**EDIT** simpler than that. After doing things the hard way I realize the symbolic constant is handled properly by the string conversion so you can just do this:

```
  print "u1=%s u2=%s u3=%s\n"%tuple(['%s'%b for b in bc])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Based on it I decided to write all boundary conditions into lists first, then assign the items from the list to `u1,u2,...` and simply use `for x in topBCs and bottomBCs: if (x==UNSET): x='UNSET'` after. That seems to work.